# How to make custom dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Im realtively new to html/css and having trouble finding a way to make an element that I want.  Ill start off with saying that I am using Material Design Lite in a rails project.

So what Im trying to do is I have a grid of search results and Im trying to create a filter bar that users can select different tags and characteristics to filter the results.  The html and form part to filter the results I can handle the part that Im having trouble figuring out is the way I want the layout...

Im trying to create a bar across the top with different categories and when the user clicks on one of the categories a box expands with all the different filtering options for that category.  Similar to a menu dropdown but looking to make it part of the group so if they choose another category it will close the first one and open the new one instead.

Im looking for a push in the right direction to find a tutorial or example that will get me in the right direction.  For a visual reference for what Im thinking the recipe website yummly uses this kind of system...heres a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can add an attribute for your top navigation's links corresponding to an ID on each individual group, then use that to target the correct tab, and fade out the rest with .siblings()

HTML

```
<div id="topbar">
    <a href="#" class="toggle" data-group="#category1">link</a>
    <a href="#" class="toggle" data-group="#category2">link</a>
</div>
<div id="groups">
    <div class="sub" id="category1">
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub" id="category2">
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
        <a href="#filter">filter</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub, .close").hide(); // hides filter tabs and close button
    $('#topbar a.toggle').click(function(){ // on click
        var category = $(this).attr("data-group"); // checks the ID to fade in
        $(".sub" + category).fadeIn().siblings(".sub").hide(); // fades in the correct subcategory and fades out all the other categories
        $(".close").fadeIn(); // fades in close button
        return false; // prevents anchor link behaviour
    });
    $("#topbar a.close").click(function(){ // close button click
        $(".sub").fadeOut(); // fades out whatever subcategory is active
        $(this).fadeOut(); // fades out close button
        return false; // prevents anchor link behaviour
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4t6k2ftd/

Comment: Thanks this points me in a good direction, i think ill be able to get it working from there

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with tabs. There are lot of tutorials for this. In your case ingredients, taste, diet(links) can be tabs. For each tab you have tab-content.For example "Diet filter options"(content) for "diet tab"(tab). When you click on "diet tab" "diet filter options"(content) is made visible and some css is added. Here is a  [tutorial](http://callmenick.com/post/simple-responsive-tabs-javascript-css).

Example tabs html

```
<ul class='tabs'>
  <li><a href='#ingredients'>Ingredients</a></li>
  <li><a href='#tastes'>Tastes</a></li>
  <li><a href='#diet'>Diet</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='ingredients'>
  Ingredients filter options
</div>
<div id='tastes'>
  tastes filter options
</div>
<div id='diet'>
  diet filter options
</div>
```

Example tabs javascript(jquery)

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
  // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
  // which tab is active and its associated content
  var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

  // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
  // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
  $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
  $active.addClass('active');

  $content = $($active[0].hash);

  // Hide the remaining content
  $links.not($active).each(function () {
    $(this.hash).hide();
  });

  // Bind the click event handler
  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    // Make the old tab inactive.
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    // Update the variables with the new link and content
    $active = $(this);
    $content = $(this.hash);

    // Make the tab active.
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();

    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Here active is class for currently active link.